# Question about infimum and supremum in a positive cone

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, convex-cone

A "lattice cone" $C$ is a cone such that $x\wedge y$ and $ x\vee y$ exist for $x,y\in C$.

But how can a positive cone contain both the supremum and the infimum? Since the relation

$$x\wedge y=x+y- x\vee y$$
would imply that $x\wedge y\in C-C\neq C$.

Maybe I'm confused with the definitions, would use some help here.

Comment: What is the cone?

Comment: A set such that 1) $\alpha x\in C$  for every $x\in C$ and $\alpha\geq 0$. 2) $C+C\subset C$ and 3) $C\cap -C=\{0\}$

Comment: Lattice ordeded group or vector space?

Comment: The cone is in a real vector lattice.

Answer (score -1):

0 is the minimum element of every positive cone.
A positive cone of more than one element cannot have a supremum.